# CORS problem with Angularjs + Spring-boot + nginx

Tags: angularjs, spring-boot, nginx, cors

So I have been pulling my hair out for a couple of days now. I have a backend server, using Spring-boot with Rest API

This server is called from a frontend interface using AngularJS, also handled by Nginx.

Everything is running locally. Whenever I try to make a request from the fronted to the backend, I get the following error:

[image]

I know what you think: Easy, just add add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' 'http://[MY_IP]'; to your nginx.conf file on the backend, and everything will work, like [here](http://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html). or [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/162429/how-do-i-add-access-control-allow-origin-in-nginx).

But it doesn't. I tried everything, moving it to different locations, putting a '*' instead of the address, enabling and disabling SSL... The only thing that works is when I manually disable Cross-Origin restrictions in the browser. And the best part is that when I do disable those restrictions, I can see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header set to http://[MY_IP] in the debug console of my browser!

Any idea of what might be going wrong?

Here is my `nginx.conf` file:

```
user nginx;
worker_processes auto;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid /run/nginx.pid;

# Load dynamic modules. See /usr/share/nginx/README.dynamic.
include /usr/share/nginx/modules/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 1024;
}

http {
    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile            on;
    tcp_nopush          on;
    tcp_nodelay         on;
    keepalive_timeout   65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include             /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type        application/octet-stream;

    # Load modular configuration files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory.
    # See http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#include
    # for more information.
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

Here is my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default.conf` file:

```
upstream backend_api {
    server 10.34.18.2:8080;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name _;

    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html;

    client_max_body_size 5M;

    location /todos {
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/todos.backend.access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/todos.backend.error.log;

        proxy_set_header HOST $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        proxy_pass http://backend_api;
    }

    location / {
        access_log  /var/log/nginx/todos.frontend.access.log;
        error_log   /var/log/nginx/todos.frontend.error.log;

        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

}
```

I create a symbolic link:

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

Comment: Have you tried changing the URL in your request code to `http://10.34.18.2:8080/docs/` (with a trailing slash)? The thing is, the https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFKpE.png screenshot doesn’t show any error — instead that screenshot just shows a request being made successfully to `http://10.34.18.2:8080/docs` and a server responding with a (non-error) 302 redirect to `http://10.34.18.2:8080/docs/`. So the server is basically just saying, *“You forgot to add the trailing slash to the request URL.”*. If there’s some other error getting logged in the devtools console, please add it to the question.

Comment: If the API endpoint your code makes the request to is the Spring Boot server, you realize that’s the server which must send back the Access-Control-Allow-Origin, right? So if the real problem you’re having is is that the browser logs a “missing Access-Control-Allow-Origin header” message in the devtools console, the fix is to configure the Spring Boot server to send back that header. If your request isn’t going to the nginx server, then your nginx config is irrelevant (and anyway, the nginx config snippets in the question don’t show the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header being set anywhere…)

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this will make the `cors` work, but it may help getting near to the solution:

`Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://[MY_IP]` is not the only header you need to take care of.

As the `Content-Type` is `application/json` and also, you are not using non simple headers, you will also have to give specific permission to `Content-Type` header, the same with `Accept-Encoding` and `DNT`

`Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type, Accept-Encoding, DNT`

I am not sure about this one for this specific `GET`, but in any case also the allowed methods:

`Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET`

And if you are sending cookies, authorization header, or cliente certificates for authentication:

`Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true`

I don't think it is your current case, but please note that returning `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` and blindly replicating the received `Origin` in the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` response, enables any site to access your server impersonating the owner of the credentials.

And just in case you are tempted, `ACAO: *` with `ACAC: true` will not work as per specification.

You may also have to take care of the `OPTIONS` method called during a cors preflight which shold be in line with what the actual call will respond.

And remember that not returning one of these headers is the way to deny it.

Ref: [CORS - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)